How would you check that you've reached market-clearing price in a market?
I have ~10 years of data about the product offerings of a given market. I can see the offers and compute unit costs. I don't have data on demand (i.e., sales).
My original idea was to check whether prices have become more stable over time. The idea being that convergence through smaller and smaller variations indicates prices reaching an equilibrium. Is there a more standardized way to check whether we've reached equilibrium?

Deleted all old comments as they are no longer relevant to current Q.
